# Override func of UIBarButtonItem used as an extension

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar, uikeyboard

In a collectionView, I'm using several textFields with different issues. All have an "extended keyboard" with custom UIBarButtons. As I need to reuse it a lot, I solved my problem with using an extension, quite similar to this one : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31010668/8162027.

My buttons are always the same: "cancel" and "Done".
But the func linked must return different things. Is there a way to override those @objc func for these 2 buttons `donePressed()` and `cancelPressed()` from my `UIcollectionView`?

Here is a screenshot of my buttons:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuHNS.jpg

Comment: Your `donePressed()` and `cancelPressed()` must return values?

Comment: Essentially my done button : endEditing the actual TF and the most important : reloadData at specific indexPath

Comment: Any suggestion ?

Comment: Maybe you can create a protocol, with these two methods `donePressed` and `cancelPressed`, and your extension `addToolBar` could receive an implementation of such protocol, which could be your `UICollectionView`, for example.

Comment: Thanks @RodrigoMorbach... I'll manage in that way. it seems to be a bit tricky, but i'll try.

Comment: Yes, it is a bit tricky. It is hard to tell without seem the code. Another possible solution would be the `ViewController` that owns the `collectionView`, overriding both `donePressed` and `cancelPressed` methods.